# How do i create a scrolling menu selector using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'd like to create a scrolling menu selector which looks like the one on : http://www.metalabdesign.com/
where the user can click "Web" , "iPhone" and "Desktop" and the selector scrolls upward or downward depending on which menu item is selected ?

Is there a plugin to do this ? I'd really appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a plugin to exactly what they did. I am not sure what this plugin would be called.

Looking at their code with firebug it seems like they are using a combination of plugins to make this.

I did not look at it fully through firebug but I recommend you do so. Since its all JavaScript you should be able to walk through all of the code that makes it and see how it is done.

These are the plugins they are using.

[easing](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)

[scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable.html)

Hope this helps.

Edit

Oh look at their  project-browser.js it seems to all the code needed to make it.

[project-browser.js](http://www.metalabdesign.com/template/js/project-browser.js)

Comment: "Oh look at their project-browser.js it seems to all the code needed to make it." --> isn't that stealing???

Comment: And your point would be?

That's the price you pay for using JavaScript anyone can look at it and anyone can take ideas from it.

If you don't like it don't use JavaScript or try to sue everyone to stop using this code that everyone can see.

Answer (score 0):

On the panic homepage: http://www.panic.com/coda/, there is a similar effect, only horizontal. And on jqueryfordesigners is the needed tutorial: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-slider-effect/

Comment: the "coda" site scroll is basically what the scrollable plugin does that is used on metalabdesign.